# Thread object in event method: use class member or create local object?

Tags: java, android, memory, object

I have a class with event method that would often be called. Let's say the method name is: onClicked. Inside the method, I would create a thread to do some stuffs.

First, I tried by creating a thread object inside the event method. The code is like this:

```
public class MyService {

    //Event method
    public void onClick() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // do some stuff here
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

But since the onClick would often be called, I'm worried if the new thread object who created everytime when the event method called would create memory-space or performance issue?

Alternatively, I can create a class member thread solution like this:

```
public class MyService {
    private Thread myThread;

    //Event method
    public void onClick() {
        myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                  // do some stuff here
            }
        });
        myThread.start();
    }
}
```

So which code is better? 1st or 2nd? Or is there other better solution?

Comment: Not a real question. You have to create a new Thread every time, you don't have the choice, so there is no 'bettter' about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the second code without reinitializing your Thread on each `OnClick()`.  This is because once a Thread has finished running, it is "dead."  Thus, subsequent calls to `start()` will fail and result in an `IllegalThreadStateException`.

It would be better to use the first code, as the GC will remove the Thread after it has completed.

Comment: Sorry, I got mistake on my 2nd code. I have updated it. So with 2nd code using a member thread variable still doesn't make any difference with 1st code in term of memory-saving or performance?

Comment: Correct, since you would have to call the Thread() constructor either way.

Answer (score 0):

I think both solutions are the same since they are creating a new thread every time `onclick`. The second one can even run into situation where a new thread is created and assigned to the global  variable `myThread`, and before it calls `start`, another `onclick` event come in and reassign the global variable leaving the previous one never start. 
I will suggest you to look at the

[ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

to control the number of threads to be allowed in here to avoid of running out of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Create and initialize [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) then onClick you can create any instance of your own class that implements Runnable interface. Point of it is to avoid create too many threads, by specifying number (size) of the pool (ExecutorService: fix thread pool). That's a better way.

As I said, you can also make small refactoring, and create own class event and implement Runnable, point is to define constructor, fields may some additional methods too.

Comment: The first solution you gave is same like evanwong's, right? For the second one (create runnable class event), would it make performance increase?

Comment: It's not a performance issue here, it's more designing the code. But you can still play with number of thread in the pool. But remember we are having deal with mobile system (battery life/performance)